# How to handle MessageBox.Show from ViewModel in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, dispatcher

I am writing a WPF application using the MVVM design pattern. I wanted to know the best possible(read "MVVM Complaint") way of doing this. Also be aware that all the code in my view model doesn't run on the UI thread. Currently I am accessing the Dispatcher in the VM using `App.Current.Dispatcher` and then calling the `MessageBox.Show()` on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create following services

```
IMessageBoxService \\ Exposes Show(string Title, String Caption)
IDispatcherService \\ Exposes Dispatch(Action action), Register(Dispatcher)
```

Then Create WPF specific implementation as

```
MessageBoxService (or WPFMessageBoxService if you wish)
DispatcherService
```

Register these to the DI/IoC container used in the application (such as Unity/MEF/Windsor)

For the dependent View Model, Pass the service through constructor like

```
public MainViewModel(IMessageBoxService messageBoxService, IDispatcherService dispatcherService)
```

Now you can use messageBoxService/dispatcherService to invoke message box through ViewModel on Dispatcher.

[MessageBox example](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.in/2012/03/showing-message-box-from-viewmodel-in.html)